# How to handle mouse over click on chart area in selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If you go mouse over on above area then 3m,6m,1y and all are visible. If you go mouse down then it disable. How to handle this type of case in selenium.

Comment: Can you post your code ? so far what have you done ? what the language ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you will have to use Action classes's mouse hover to get the pop up for months.

....Use developer tool to highlight the chart on which you need to hover the mouse, now hover the mouse to get those month's pop ups. and see in developer tools for changes in dom so that you can get their xpaths. Make sure you use "driver.click" to click on months. you can try xpath= //*[.='3m']. Just try to find out exact value of * using developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for quick response.

I have tried with your solution but the xpath is not working and give the nosuchelementexception. Because in the HTML Dom there are 2 iframe. Inside child frame we goto mouse over then it's visible . We mouse down then it is disapper. So my question is how to pause the mouse over section at certain time period so that all text are like 3m,6m,YTD,1y,All are visible and click one by one
In the DOm first div tag then the sequence order like
 ,, then 3m is displayed .
Could you please provide me the alternative solution?